# Generating Random Number

Tags: php, random

Does anyone know how to generate random numbers from -1 to 1. Or is it even possible to do? I've researched already and i only get answers for generating random numbers from 0 to N. By the way, i'm using PHP.

Please help! Thanks in advance to those who'll answer!

Comment: There can't be negative random numbers. EVER. You'll open a stargate portal to hell and we'll just die. Seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate random number between 0 and 2, then subtract 1 from generated number.

Comment: Oh I haven't realized that, and now i think it's the most practical thing to do.Thank you! That will do.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a random function that generates numbers from 0.0 to 1.0, multiply the result by two and subtract 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for integers:

```
$array = range(- 1, 1, 1);
echo $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)]; // example 0
```

Or this for floats with precision declared in the third parameter of `range()`:

```
$array = range(- 1, 1, 0.1);
echo $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)]; // example -0.9
```